# More efficient way to compare 2 enormous tables in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a request who compare a table of ~ 17 millions items with another of more than 80 millions items.
I use the "IN" operator:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM table1 
WHERE mykey IN (SELECT mykey FROM table2 WHERE (thematique = '1'))
```

This is perfectly working, but in a very very longtime...

Is it a bester way, anyway a faster way, to do the same ?

Maybe without the "IN" operator ?

Comment: Is mykey key, indexed, unique?

Comment: mykey is not indexed. mykey is unique in table1, but not in table2.

Comment: btw what you mean `compare`?  in this case you are counting how many records are of one type.

Comment: Try an exists query - very often that is faster than an `IN` especially if `table2.mykey` is indexed. Depending on how often `thematique` with the  value `1` appears an index on that column might be better (btw: if `thematique` is a number, you should compare it to a number `'1'` is a string literal. `1` is a number)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `IN(..)` and `EXISTS(...)` result in the same query plan for not-NULL-able columns.

Comment: @wildplasser: I have seen situation where a co-related `exists()` actually did have a different execution plan. And if `mykey` has many duplicates in table2 it _could_ make a difference. I'm not saying it **will** - just that it's worth trying. But without any indexes that is not going to perform well regardless which construct is used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you can give an example I *could* believe you. (in both cases the resulting plan would be a hash-aggregation, unless work_mem is too small, in which case it would either become an indexjoin if a usable index is available, or a materialize+sort step, when not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to speed up this query is to have an index on `table2 (thematique, mykey)`. Then the thematique 1 records are easily found and their mykeys accessed right away without having to access the table even.

I don't think it will make a big difference whether to use `IN` or `EXISTS` or `INTERSECT` (though MySQL was known for being weak on IN clauses). As `INTERSECT` is made for getting distinct values found in both sets, it would be my first try here, though.

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select mykey from table1
  intersect
  select mykey from table2 where thematique = '1'
) intersection;
```

Comment: Indeed, intersect seems to be much faster ! But is your request has to return exactly the same count as mine ? If not, I not sure to inderstand the differences between IN and INTERSECT

Comment: INTERSECT takes the two sets of mykey and gives the intersection of the two sets (unique results). As mykey is unique in table1, you get the same result by asking "give me all mykey from table1 that are also IN / that also EXIST in table2".

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with left join?

You need index on `T1.mykey`, `T2.mykey` and `T2.thematique`

And probably a composite index willl be better `(T2.mykey,T2.thematique)`

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T1.mykey)
 FROM table1  T1
 LEFT JOIN table2  T2
        ON T1.mykey = T2.mykey
       AND T2.thematique = '1'
 WHERE T2.mykey is not NULL
```

Comment: Will return duplicated rows since table2.mykey contains duplicates.